# How to check for presence of intestinal parasites and what's the procedure to get rid of them?

Tags: parasites, ct-scans, intestine, filariasis

What are the standard procedures of detecting intestinal parasites in the body (e.g. *[Ascaris lumbricoides](https://www.google.co.uk/search?tbm=isch&q=Ascaris%20lumbricoides)*) and what are the methods to get rid of them in case they're present?

Can CT scan detect them, or you've to do some special tests?

Comment: Are you asking about systemic infections?

Comment: There are all sorts of parasites. I think you need to narrow this down or it's just too broad.

Comment: @CareyGregory I'm aware that there are all sorts of parasites, that's why my question consist specific strand of the parasite as example to follow.

Comment: I think that without even limiting it to intestinal parasites, it's definitely too broad.  Just giving an example of a parasite doesn't really limit the scope.  The way you check for pubic lice has no relation to the way you check for hookworms.  I can point to whole textbooks on the subject, making me think that it is too broad in its current form.

Comment: @AtlLED Narrowed down by 'intestinal parasites'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The intestinal and luminal protozoa are normally identified in stool specimens, the blood protozoa by examination of blood films with microscopy (malaria), and lymph node biopsy and serological testing (toxoplasmosis), nematodes, cestodes and trematodes by identifying eggs/larvae in stool/sputum/urine specimens.  Advanced disease states might require imaging such as MRI of the central nervous system in [neurocystercicosis](http://www.hindawi.com/journals/ipid/2009/180742/).

Treatment is specific for the parasite in question.

You can read textbook chapters on [parasitology](http://www.microbiologybook.org/book/parasit-sta.htm) online.

Answer (score 5):

Intestinal parasites can be detected by stool tests (and additional blood tests if necessary). Note that these tests are often false negative, which means they may not detect parasites even if you have them, so if you still suspect you have parasites, you need to repeat the tests. Treatment is with antiparasitic drugs dependent on the type of parasite.

When parasites invade other body organs, CT, MRI or organ biopsy can be used.

Source: [Common Intestinal Parasites (American Family Physician)](http://www.aafp.org/afp/2004/0301/p1161.html)

On [Centers of Disease Control and Prevention](http://www.cdc.gov/parasites/az/index.html) you have an extensive A-Z list of parasitic diseases with links to detailed descriptions of the symptoms, tests and treatment.